# Problems with libraries for programs [GParted, Krita]

Tags: gparted, libraries, shared-library, krita

GParted or Krita do not start. If you run them through the terminal, you get an error about the libraries.

```
    Unit -.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
/usr/sbin/gpartedbin: error while loading shared libraries: libpangomm-1.4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

krita: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Widgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I changed the config settings in `ld.so.conf` (I specified folders for libraries, it's useless)

```
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/local/lib
/root/etc/lib
/
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I am newbie.

The output of `apt-cache policy krita gparted libqt5widgets5` is on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/JLFKjYFg).

Comment: You chose very strange way to use and install software. What was wrong with installing them from repository: `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install krita gparted`? By the way libraries are located in the following packages - [libqt5widgets5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libQt5Widgets.so.5) and [libpangomm-1.4-1v5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=xenial&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=libpangomm-1.4.so.1&searchon=contents).

Comment: @N0rbert Very strange? These programms installed from official Ubuntu "store"

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy krita gparted  libqt5widgets5 libpangomm-1.4-1v5` to the question.

Comment: The whole text does not fit into the comment, but I have everything set.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this error is seen because you do not have the libraries installed.

You can check your filesystem for the file, using `dpgk`, but this only shows files you have installed and could be used to confirm the file exists:

```
dpkg -S libQt5Widgets.so.5
```

To find which package has the library file, you can search the [Ubuntu Packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) website, or use `apt-file`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-file
$ sudo apt-file update
$ sudo apt-file find libQt5Widgets.so.5
libqt5widgets5:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.5
libqt5widgets5:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
libqt5widgets5:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.5.1
```

This means that you need to install `libqt5widgets5` to get the library file:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5widgets5
```

It is best to let the system manage libraries with `apt` and rely less on manual intervention with tools like `ldconfig`, or building from source when hard work has been done to provide secure and stable packages.

---

When you install an application through a package, the package will have a list of dependencies.  If you're installing programs like `gparted` and `krita` using `apt`, they should automatically download and install dependencies, with your permission.  You can try re-installing the dependency in case something strange happened:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libqt5widgets5
```

Comment: I've done everything. But it still does not work.

Comment: Can you please update the question with some details such as how `gparted` and `krita` were installed?  On which version of Ubuntu are you?  Have you recently done a `dist-upgrade`, or version upgrade?  Have you reverted your settings to `ld`?  Did `libqt5widgets5` install or reinstall?  Have you tried restarting since?  There are other people with questions that will help us, such as `apt-cache policy krita gparted libqt5widgets5` output.  Large text outputs can be stored on [Ubuntu's pastebin](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) and [linked to](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @Lazelis [Please don't say “I have tried everything”](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17874/please-dont-say-i-have-tried-everything?cb=1), and please answer my questions (if `apt-cache policy krita gparted libqt5widgets5 libpangomm-1.4-1v5` output is long, use PasteBin or something similar).

Comment: I think in this context @Lazelis means they have tried all of 'everything' inside my proposed answer, but we will likely need more information to resolve the issue.

Comment: @earthmeLon OK, let's wait for adequate actions of OP. Now I vote to close as unclear.

Comment: I apologize for being late, I had to go to bed.
https://pastebin.com/JLFKjYFg
These programs installed from Ubuntu Software Center, just one click.
Ubuntu was installed yesterday, so all the updates were downloaded yesterday.
libqt5widgets5 reinstalled many times.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic